# Error in zip::unzip(zipfile = newfile, exdir = folder)

Tags: r, zip

Good evening, I'm trying to generate a Word table and I get this error which makes no sense to me, because I'm not working with a zip file:

```
Error in zip::unzip(zipfile = newfile, exdir = folder) : 
  zip error: `Cannot open zip file 
`C:\Users\archs\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6jpmHp\file32342d9d4d0a.docx` for reading` in file 
`zip.c:140`
```

This is the code that I'm running:

```
tabledoc <- file.choose()
read_docx(tabledoc) %>%
  body_add_par("\n") %>%
  body_add_par("Table 1: Proportion of correct choices made Polistes dominula paper wasps 
during transitive inference trials with unfamiliar stimuli (CIsusing Student’s t).\n") %>%
  body_add_flextable(table1) %>%
  body_add_par("\n") %>%
  print(tabledoc)
shell.exec(tabledoc)
```

Comment: `docx` is a compressed format which is why it needs to be uncompressed before use.  The error is occurring because the file being used might have the `.docx` extension but it is not (or not being recognised as) a `docx` file.

Comment: Thank you, how can I uncompress it? I created a new .docx file from zero...

Comment: You don't need to manually uncompress it - it's done automatically by the package - I was just explaining the context of the error you encountered.  How did you create the file exactly?  If you just created a text file and then changed the extension that explains your issue.

Comment: No I simply right click and select new --> Microsoft Word, that's it. I didn't modify anything.  I'm using Office 2007...

Comment: OK the function can't read a file created this way.  Just use `read_docx()` (with no filename) and it will create a blank default for you.

Comment: Actually I just downloaded a random .docx file from google, erased all contents and used it in R, it worked! Thank you!